# How many cals do I need for a server handing out profiles

Tags: windows-server-2003, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Suppose I have a windows 2003 server which hosts 500 roaming profiles. Do i need 500 cals for each user accessing his profile. How does this work?

Answer (score 4):

This [Microsoft Volume Licensing CAL Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/client-access-license.aspx) will probably spell out everything you need to know.

**User CALs:**

> With the User CAL, you purchase a CAL
>   for every user who accesses the server
>   to use services such as file storage
>   or printing, regardless of the number
>   of devices they use for that access.
>   Purchasing a User CAL might make more
>   sense if your company employees need
>   to have roaming access to the
>   corporate network using multiple
>   devices, or from unknown devices, or
>   simply have more devices than users in
>   your organization.

[image]

**Device CALs:**

> With a Device CAL, you purchase a CAL
>   for every device that accesses your
>   server, regardless of the number of
>   users who use that device to access
>   the server. Device CALs may make more
>   economic and administrative sense if
>   your company has workers who share
>   devices, for example, on different
>   work shifts.

[image]

And on a slight technicality, if you purchase User CALs, you only need one per user, not 500 per user..

Answer (score -2):

No.

You need NONE, provided every MACHINE retrieving the profile has a CAL assigned to it.

Now, the user probably has a CAL anyway, as... guess what ;) There are other computers it needs.

If not, you need ONE CAL FOR EVERY USER.

Comment: I don't understand how the user could already have a CAL? Because as I understand it (and as they tried to sell it to me some years ago) each user (or device) needs a CAL for each server so, even if the user has a CAL for another server, he will need a new one for the new server.

Comment: it's not a CAL for each server in a domain.  One single User CAL covers all the servers in the domain.

Comment: As it has been repeatedly explained to me: one single device CAL (for example, assigned to a workstation) allows any users using that specific workstation to connect to any server that the organization owns. One single user CAL (for example, assigned to "Stemen") allows the specific user "Stemen" to access any server using any device that the organization owns. I have specifically asked whether the boundary is on domain or organization, and the response I've received has always been "organization."