# Does Office 2010 Professional Plus include the CAL for Office Communications Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, microsoft-office-2010

I know office 2010 pro plus includes office communicator, but is that the CAL for accessing the server? I am trying to figure out if i just need to buy the Communications server software or if i need the server software and the CALs.

Comment: Have you asked Microsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just had to deal with exactly this issue, here is my understanding: (DISCLAIMER: Always verify with your vendor!!)
There are 3 licenses for Communicator and OCS:

- License #1 is for the Communicator client. This is included with Office Professional Plus.

  License #2 is for OCS Standard connectivity, this gives you basic Communicator functionality. IM, Video, etc...

  License #3 is for OCS Enterprise, and this is additive - you need this in ADDITION to a Standard license. This gives you more of the Unified Messaging capabilities.

There's more detailed information on the [MS OCS site](http://www.microsoft.com/communicationsserver/en/us/pricing-licensing.aspx) that will tell you what the Standard and Enterprise CAL's for OCS give you, but to answer your basic question, NO. The License you get with Office ProPlus is only for the Communicator software itself, NOT for accessing the OCS server.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question, he knows he has to buy the OCS License. He just wants to know if/what CAL comes with MOS2010 ProPlus, as it's not clear from the MOS page. But as you answered Office 2010 ProPlus comes with the standard CAL.

Comment: Not to be disagreeable, but I think you are misunderstanding my answer, and I think it's terminology related. He needs to buy the server and the CAL's. What he doesn't need to buy is Communicator - a software license for that program is included with Office ProPlus. A software license, however, is not a CAL - these are 2 different types of licenses. He can use Communicator, but not to access an OCS instance unless he also buys the CAL's, which come in Standard and Enterprise flavors.

Comment: Yes that is what i am trying to sort out. My Boss seems to think that the CAL is included with the Office Product. I am thinking that it is not included.

Comment: It is my understanding that you are correct. Office includes a license to USE Communicator, but NOT a CAL to access the OCS server. These are 2 separate licenses, because heaven forbid they should make licensing easy.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 R2 is included in Office Professional Plus 2010 Volume Licensing options and Microsoft Office Communicator 2010 is scheduled for release in the second half of 2010. So both communicator versions are included.

[Compare Office 2010 suites available through Volume Licensing](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/office-2010-volume-licensing-suites-comparison-FX101825637.aspx)

To have OCS-services, Core CAL Suite and Enterprise CAL Suite or Core CAL Suite and OCS CAL Suite(s) are needed. Additionally Live Meeting requires OCS Enterprise CAL. OCS CAL Suites can be purchased separately w/ Core CAL Suite.

Microsoft Core CAL and Enterprise CAL Suites:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to dig into the agreements/documentation, but I believe that the Communicator program is not yet included with Office 2010 ProPlus, but the CAL is included for Communicator 2010 (can be downgraded to 2007). When Communicator 2010 is released the full program will be included.

Comment: Interesting Thanks. 
I notices that the server version for that was 2007, and was wondering why it was not 2010. I did see where Communicator "14" was out. I wish they would pick a number schema and stay with it. 

And simplify their versions.

I need to find a linux shop to work for.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't think any of us here are Microsoft Licensing experts.  If someone here is, I'm sorry.

It's my understanding that that CAL is only for Communications server.  You'll still need CALs for Windows Server...see [this similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/171495/how-many-cals-do-i-need-for-a-server-handing-out-profiles).

I have go-to people I can contact at my various vendors to get those questions answered and be relatively assured that I'm in compliance.

Do you have a vendor you can contact?

Comment: I have a vendor i can check with, but then i will get numerous follow up calls wanting to know when we would like to buy. So i though i would as to see if anyone knew.

Comment: It's sad that it's full time job being an expert at Microsoft licensing for some people.  Why must Microsoft make these damn things so convoluted

Comment: I think they're experts at all sorts of licensing schemes.  Microsoft doesn't hold a monopoly there surprisingly...